# How to display output from rake task to the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, progress-bar, mechanize

I have this rake file which scraping data from a website. While this script scraping the data, I am using rake-progressbar gem to track its progress. However, right now I can see the progress only in my terminal and only if I run the rake file in my terminal by typing: "rake testing2".

What I want now is to be able to see the progress in the browser when I click the link that trigger my rake file.

**This is my home view which contains the link to trigger the rake file(testing2.rake):**

```
<div>
    <p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>

    <h3>Scrape data:</h3>
    <%= link_to "Scrape",:action => 'scrape' %>

</div>
```

**This is my home controller:**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def scrape
    %x[rake testing2]
    redirect_to root_url
  end   

end
```

**This is my rake file(testing2.rake) which contains the codes to scrape the data as well as the code of the progress bar:**

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'date'
require 'json'
require 'rake-progressbar'


task :testing2 => [:environment] do


    agent = Mechanize.new

    last_page_number = 1

    for pg_number in 1..last_page_number do

        puts "Scrapping..."

        page = agent.get("https://www.congress.gov/members?page=#{pg_number}")
        page_links = page.links_with(href: %r{.*/member/\w+})

        page_links_size = page_links.size

        member_links = page_links
        bar = RakeProgressbar.new(100)

        members = member_links.map do |link|        

          member = link.click

          name = member.search('title').text.split('|')[0]
          institution = member.search('td~ td+ td').text.split(':')[0]

          stripActivities = activities.reject { |x| x.length  == 1 }


          {
            name: name.strip,
            institution: institution.strip
          }

          bar.inc

        end


        bar.finished

    end

end
```

**And below is the output in the terminal with the progress bar showing:**

[image]

So, how can i display this progress onto the browser?

Comment: You want to run rake tasks from the browser? That seems like a bad idea from a security perspective.

Comment: @pguardiario oh? I don't know about that, but security doesnt really matter in this app. Anyways, could you tell me where is the more suitable place to put my testing2.rake code in my rails app if it is not a rake task? Because I have different codes to scrape different websites and I couldnt think any other place to put them right now other than inside this tasks folder

Comment: If it's for display in the browser it usually goes in a view but that might not make sense in your case.

Answer (score 0):

#### progress bar:

You can store progress in database and show it in browser page.

#### parsing:

remove rake task and just run it as `ActiveJob` when user click to link